# How to test that observable uses correct schedulers in RxJava?

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, rx-java

I have the following class (simplified):

```
public class Usecase<T> {
    private final Observable<T> get;
    private final Scheduler observeScheduler;

    public Usecase(Observable<T> get, Scheduler observeScheduler) {
        this.get = get;
        this.observeScheduler = observeScheduler;
    }

    public Observable<T> execute() {
        return get.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(observeScheduler);
    }
}
```

And I'm writing unit tests for it. How can I test that `subscribeOn` and `observeOn` were called with correct values?

I try the following:

```
    Observable<String> observable = mock(Observable.class);
    Usecase<String> usecase = new Usecase(observable, Schedulers.computation());
    usecase.execute();

    verify(observable).subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()); // should fail here, but passes
    verify(observable).observeOn(Schedulers.computation());   // should pass, but fails: Missing method call for verify(mock) here
```

The above fails (I think) because `subscribeOn` and `observeOn` are `final` methods. So may be there is some other way to ensure that the observable uses correct schedulers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[There is a way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29364009/5623874) to indirectly access both threads on which an observable is operating and being observed, which means you can in fact verify the `Observable` uses the correct schedulers.

We're confined to verifying threads by name. Fortunately, threads used by `Schedulers.io()` are named with a consistent prefix that we can match against. Here's the (full?) list of schedulers that have unique prefixes for reference:

- `Schedulers.io()` - *RxCachedThreadScheduler*
- `Schedulers.newThread()` - *RxNewThreadScheduler*
- `Schedulers.computation()` - *RxComputationThreadPool*

To verify an Observable was **subscribed** to on the **IO thread**:

```java
// Calling Thread.currentThread() inside Observer.OnSubscribe will return the
// thread the Observable is running on (Schedulers.io() in our case)
Observable<String> obs = Observable.create((Subscriber<? super String> s) -> {
    s.onNext(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    s.onCompleted();
})

// Schedule the Observable
Usecase usecase = new Usecase(obs, Schedulers.immediate());
Observable usecaseObservable = usecase.execute();

// Verify the Observable emitted the name of the IO thread
String subscribingThread = usecaseObservable.toBlocking().first();
assertThat(subscribingThread).startsWith("RxCachedThreadScheduler");
```

To verify an Observable was **observed** on the **computation thread**, you can use `TestSubscriber#getLastSeenThread` to access the last thread used for observing.

```java
TestSubscriber<Object> subscriber = TestSubscriber.create();
UseCase usecase = new UseCase(Observable.empty(), Schedulers.computation())
usecase.execute().subscribe(subscriber);

// The observable runs asynchronously, so wait for it to complete
subscriber.awaitTerminalEvent();
subscriber.assertNoErrors();

// Verify the observable was observed on the computation thread
String observingThread = subscriber.getLastSeenThread().getName();
assertThat(observingThread).startsWith("RxComputationThreadPool");
```

No third-party libraries or mocking are necessary, though I am using [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/) for the fluent `startsWith` assertion.

Answer (score 2):

Applying operators on the `Observable` returns a new `Observable` thus any subsequent operator application will happen on a different object. You'd have to follow the composition graph in an Observable to discover what operators were applied and with what parameters.

This is not supported in RxJava and you have to rely on internal details and reflection.

Generally, you can't assume anything about the location where events will come from but you can apply `observeOn` to make sure they get to the thread of your chosing.